# How to notate that a list of objects is part of the same set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How do I notate that the same conditions apply to a list of mathematical objects? For example, how would I notate that both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are members of the real numbers without defining the condition on each term separately? I.e. how would I simplify: $C_1\in\mathbb{R},\quad$ $C_2\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: a,b,c,... in R.

Comment: Do I need brackets around a,b,c such as (a,b,c) or is the comma sufficient?

Comment: You could write $C_1,C_2\in \mathbb{R}$ or if you prefer, $\{C_1, C_2\}\subset\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks, I have learned all that I have wanted to know.